# Scala Unit Testing - Mocking an implicitly wrapped function

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito, implicit-conversion, scalamock

I have a question concerning unit tests that I'm trying to achieve using Mockito in Scala. I've also looked up ScalaMock but it sounds like the feature is not provided as well. I suppose that maybe I'm looking from a narrow way to the solution and there might be a different perspective or approach to what im doing so all your opinions are welcomed.

Basically, I want to mock a function that is available to the object using **implicit conversion**, and I don't have any control to change how that is done. Since I'm a user to the library. The concrete example is similar to the following scenario

```
rdd: RDD[T] = //existing RDD
sqlContext: SQLContext = //existing sqlcontext
import sqlContext.implicits._
rdd.toDF() 
/*toDF() doesn't originally exist at RDD but is implicitly added when importing sqlContext.implicits._*/
```

Now In the testing, I'm mocking the `rdd` and the `sqlContext` and I want to mock the `toDF()` function. I Can't mock the function `toDF()` since it doesn't exist on the RDD level. Even if I do a simple trick, importing the mocked `sqlContext.implicit._`  I get an error that any function that is not publicaly available to the object can't be mocked. I even tried to mock the code that is implicitly executed until `toDF()` but I get stuck with Final/Pivate[in accessible] classes that I also can't mock. Your suggestions are more than welcomed. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why would you want to mock all this stuff?  What's wrong with actually using the real implicit conversion and even a real RDD?

Comment: away from the fact of mocking the RDD .. this idea of mocking an implicitly wrapped function is a research thing for me that I would like to find an answer for. you can consider any other example, not this concrete one :) ...

Comment: OK, I just wonder when it would ever be useful to mock those.  I don't think implicit functions should access the DB, or call web services or anything like that.

Comment: @herman ... in my example we implicitly convert an RDD into a dataframe and store it back "structured" to hdfs. we don't want this to happen in unit testing! Do you :) ?

Comment: Maybe not.  What do you want to happen in your test?  I mean, what is the code that you actually want to test?